# strange issue of undefined in url in UAT env. in local it is working:

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-native, rest

can anybody please help on this.

I have strange issue in `API`. My backend is created in `php` and UI in `react`.
in my env file below path are present.

```
API_URL=http://localhost:8080
FRONT_URL=http://localhost:80
```

so `API_URL` is for `backend` and `FRONT_URL` is for `UI`. I have called my API like below in `react`.

```
 axios
      .get(process.env.API_URL+ '/code';)
      .then()
      .error
```

my code is working properly. same API I can access from `react`as well as `postman`. there is no issue.
But when we deployed our application in UAT URL is appending `undefined` between API name and API URL.
Below are `API` value in `UAT` env file.

```
FRONT_URL=https://uat-solve.dell.com
API_URL=https://api.uat-solve.dell.com
```

Now my application throwing error. it is not running. when I checked what `URL` it is trying to reach out then it came below.

```
https://api.uat-solve.dell.com/undefined/code
```

It is appending `undefined` in between. when I tried to access same `url` from postman after removing `undefined` output is coming.

What could be the possible reason of it? this is the new component in `react`. existing application working properly

Edit 1:-

I changed env variable to `REACT_APP`* but still it did not work.

Comment: Do environmental variables in react have to prefix with `REACT_APP_`?

Comment: Try changing `API_URL` to `REACT_APP_API_URL` in the `.env` and in the axios request. THEN RESTART THE NODE APP FROM THE TERMINAL, If you're using `npm start` it won't update when you change .env

Comment: I really doubt if it is the issue? how changing variable name will make difference?

Comment: ... Your project can consume variables declared in your environment as if they were declared locally in your JS files. By default you will have NODE_ENV defined for you, and any other environment variables starting with REACT_APP_. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: actually your answere makes sense, butthen  how existing application accessing same url and it is working?

Comment: are you using `Nginx` to deploy your UAT react app?

Comment: @ShrutiSharma make sure `process.env.API_URL` variables value is accessible during build, which seems to be the cause for `undefined` being appended in the url

Answer (score 1):

The Create React App documentation states that you must prefix all environment variables within your .env files with REACT_APP_ for them to be available from within your code `process.env.REACT_APP_<variable name>`

If you don't want to use `REACT_APP_` prefix, you can use [env-create-react-app](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-create-react-app)

Comment: Is there any other way to resolve this issue? because changing name of variable will be like changing name of variable in every js file. we have around 100 components.

Comment: Haha, you can use the global search, replace them all in a sec and make sure to re-start your app after updating the .env file

Comment: value of process.env.api_url is not coming as undefined. after this url value undefined is getting added.

Answer (score 1):

Try using backticks(``)

For Example : `` `${process.env.API_URL}/code` ``

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the .env file in your root folder(same place where you have your package.json) and NOT in your src folder.

Answer (score 1):

You mention you changed your environment variables to start with `REACT_APP` - do you have a trailing underscore? They should start with `REACT_APP_`.